# Send multiple choice questions from server to android?

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to develop the android app that will receive the multiple choice questions from the server and then send the choices that user clicks to server. I am trying to send the multiple choice question using json. My problem is that I cannot get the question and choices in android. I could not figure out how to do it. How could I write json and android code to complete the task. Below is my code:

*data.json*

```
{"questions":
         [

 {
 "text":"What is the capital city of France?",
 "options":
   [
 "Tokyo",
 "Berlin",
 "Helsinki",
 "Paris"
 ]
 },

 {
 "text":"What is 2 + 2?",
 "options":[
 "3",
 "4",
 "5",
 "6"
 ]
 },

 {
 "text":"How many grams are in a kilogram?",
 "options":[
 "10",
 "100",
 "1,000",
 "10,000"
   ]
 }
]
};
```

*data.php*

```
<?php

    header('Content-type:application/json');

$data =file_get_contents('/var/www/html/data.json');

$out =json_encode($data);

echo ($out);

?>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.multiple;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private ListView listview;
    List<HashMap<String,String>> collect= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        populate p = new populate();
        p.execute();
    }

    public class populate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
            public Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.i("size","adfasdfa");
                        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet post = new HttpGet("http://192.168.10.120/data.php");
                        HttpResponse res= client.execute(post);
                        HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();

                        String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                        Log.i("response",response);

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String questions = obj.optString("questions").toString();

                        Log.d("lets c what is formes",questions);


                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(questions);
                        String[] qns = new String[array.length()];


                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                        {
                            qns[i]= array.getString(i);
                            Log.i("list of question",qns[i]);
                        }


                    }
                    catch(IOException ex){}

                    catch(JSONException ex){}

                return  null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

        }

        String[] str = new String[]{"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"};
        int[] val = new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.checkBox1,R.id.checkBox2,R.id.checkBox3,R.id.checkBox4};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to fetch the JSON from the response coming in post or get request.

```
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
JSONObject jObjGmail = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

After getting the JSON parse it and use it to display in the way you want.

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated one so try to use UrlConnectionManager